# How to convert a list of data contract class to an integer array in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to convert a List of DataContract class to an integer array in C#.
while I am trying to do this , I am getting the below error.

> error CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'System.Array.ConvertAll(TInput[], 
>   System.Converter)' cannot be inferred from the usage. 
>   Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Could you please let me know how to resolve this error.
"TopicDetails" is a data contract class which contains objects(strings)

```
 List<TopicDetails> topicDetails3;
            TopicDetails[] arr = topicDetails3.ToArray();  
            int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(arr,int.Parse);


//topicDetails is a data-contract
CreateSubscriptions<List<TopicDetails>(topicDetails);

//Here TopicDetails is a class (data contract) as follows.

public class TopicDetails
{
    protected object baseObjectType;  //string
    protected object topic;            //string

    public TopicDetails();

    [DataMember]
    public object BaseObjectType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public object TopicID { get; set; }

    public static TopicDetails CreateTopic<T, mT>(IComparable<T> objectType, IComparable<mT> objectID);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown the code that fails, nor do we know where you expect to get the integers from...

Answer (score 0):

It is really clear that the code is wrong. You cannot cast an array of `TopicDetails` to an array of `int` as you do:

```
TopicDetails[] arr = topicDetails3.ToArray();  
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(arr,int.Parse);
```

I'm not sure but I guess you want to have the `Ids` of all TopicDetails.
You cannot use `int.Parse` because it accepts only a string. You need for that the static class `System.Convert`.

```
TopicDetails[] arr = topicDetails3.ToArray();  
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(arr.Select(t => t.TopicID).ToArray(), System.Convert.ToInt32);
```

Comment: Actually I want the List<TopicDetails> to an integer array.  Is it possible ?  Because I need to pass this  integer array to C++ which accepts a parameter  const vector<int> &optList   through Managed C++ (C++/CLI).      If i am using the code provided by you I am getting the below error. Could you please let me know how to resolve this.    error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Array.ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>(TInput[], System.Converter<TInput,TOutput>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Sorry I missed something.

Comment: But can I convert the whole  List<TopicDetials>  to an integer array ? Here TopicDetails is a data contract class.     can we convert the List<TopicDetails> to an XML string and then can we convert it to an integer array. ? Because I need to pass the List<TopicDetials> where in TopicDetails is a data contract class  to C++/CLI and then to C++      const vector<int> &optList

Comment: Sorry I cannot follow. My code gives you a array of `int` that you can pass to a C++/CLI method. You cannot convert a List TopicDetails to an int, because is no convertible.

Comment: okay. But Can i convert   public object BaseObjectType { get; set; } to an integer array ? As per my understanding BaseObjectType  is a string       (Ex:  ":EQUIPMENT" ). but when i convert it to integer array it is giving exception as      "Input string was not in a correct format."              Any idea on this ?  I am using the below code.                                   TopicDetails[] arr = topicDetails.ToArray();
                int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(arr.Select(t => t.BaseObjectType).ToArray(), System.Convert.ToInt32);

Comment: TopicDetails[] arr = topicDetails.ToArray();                                                 int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(arr.Select(t => t.BaseObjectType).ToArray(), System.Convert.ToInt32);                                                                                                                                                               it is giving exception as "Input string was not in a correct format."  BaseObjectType is a string (Ex: ":EQUIPMENT" ).

Comment: You should learn the basic concept of .NET. A string is not an integer. This will only work if "BaseObjectType" has a value of "1", "34" or any kind of integer as string. If my anser helped you, please accept and upvote it.

Comment: Could you please help me how to convert    " BaseObjectType"   is a string (Ex: ":EQUIPMENT" ). to an integer array.   I am trying using the below code.but i know that it could be wrong. But what is the correct approach in the below code.                                                 TopicDetails[] arr = topicDetails.ToArray(); int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(arr.Select(t => t.BaseObjectType).ToArray(), System.Convert.ToInt32);

Comment: Could you please help me how to convert " BaseObjectType" which is a string  (Ex: ":EQUIPMENT" ) in the above data contract,    to an integer array.

Comment: I need to convert "BaseObjectType"  which is a string (Ex: ":EQUIPMENT" ) in the above data contract, to an integer array.    using  something like the below code:                                                TopicDetails[] arr = topicDetails.ToArray(); int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll(arr.Select(t => t.BaseObjectType).ToArray(), System.Convert.ToInt32);

Comment: The following code satisfies my requirement of converting List of datacontracts to an integer array. Please take a look at the code.

Comment: int[] data;

                var obj = topicDetails;// topicDetails= new List<TopicDetails> { };// List of DataContracts{ BaseObjectType = ":EQUIPMENT", TopicID = "42" };
                var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<TopicDetails>));

                using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);data = new int[stream.Length];
                    stream.Position = 0;for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                        data[i] = stream.ReadByte(); }

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following code working in answering my question. Please take a look at it.

```
            int[] data;

            var obj = topicDetails;// topicDetails= new List<TopicDetails> { };// List of DataContracts{ BaseObjectType = ":EQUIPMENT", TopicID = "42" };
            var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<TopicDetails>));

            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);

                data = new int[stream.Length];
                stream.Position = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                    data[i] = stream.ReadByte();
            }
```